# Adding a button to a image with text so it can navigate to the next page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

firstly thanks for the help. Just started in flutter/dart and have a issue I can't work my way out of.

I have a scaffod with a appbar and a body and in the body is a container with a gridview with a decoration box with a image with a text and now want to add a way for when this is clicked go to another page (invoices). Thought this required a button as the last step, but not sure where to paste the final code portion

```
import 'package:cfo360app/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[50],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('CFO360'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: Text('logout'),
            onPressed: () async {
              await _auth.signout();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [
                        Color(0x66424554),
                        Color(0x99424554),
                        Color(0xcc424554),
                        Color(0xff424554),
                      ]
                  ),
                ),

                  child: GridView.count(
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                    crossAxisCount: 4,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Material(
                        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                        ),
                        child:Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[ Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage('assets/images/camera.jpg'),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover
                            )
                          ),
                             child: Center(child: Text("invoices",
                             style:TextStyle(fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.white,
                                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                                ),
                            child: Center(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Invoices()),
                              );
                            },
                                ),
                          ),
                          ),
                      ],
                      ),
                      ),
```

any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Keeps asking to add required argument child.

Comment: I think you error occurs because you have to provide a child Widget in your [ElevatedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already said what's the problem you need to provide argument for Invoices and you don't really need a button to navigate to another page you can wrap it with InkWell or GestureDetector.

```
import 'package:cfo360app/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue[50],
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('CFO360'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
    elevation: 0.0,
    actions: <Widget>[
      TextButton.icon(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        label: Text('logout'),
        onPressed: () async {
          await _auth.signout();
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
  body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
    value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
    child: GestureDetector(
      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [
                  Color(0x66424554),
                  Color(0x99424554),
                  Color(0xcc424554),
                  Color(0xff424554),
                ]),
          ),
          child: GridView.count(
            mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            children: <Widget>[
              Material(
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                ),
                child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => Invoices(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage('assets/images/camera.jpg'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "invoices",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: Hi there As I only started using flutter over the weekend, could you assist with where and how inkwell would be used in this scenario?

Comment: First remove the extra child that has the navigation then wrap the container with InkWell as example and onTap provide Navigator.push (...);

Comment: Morning

much appreciated for the assistance, it worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

A container cannot have more than one child, it is a Single-child layout widget. What you did was put the elevated button right inside a container that already has a child. With the layout you have, you may not necessarily need an `Elevated Button`; What you can alternatively do is to add a `Gesture Detecture` widget as the direct parent of the `Container` widget.
I have edited your code, try it now, it should work the way you want.

```
import 'package:cfo360app/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[50],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('CFO360'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: Text('logout'),
            onPressed: () async {
              await _auth.signout();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [
                        Color(0x66424554),
                        Color(0x99424554),
                        Color(0xcc424554),
                        Color(0xff424554),
                      ]),
                ),
                child: GridView.count(
                  mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                  crossAxisCount: 4,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Material(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                      ),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: (){
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => Invoices()),
                              );
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      image: AssetImage(
                                          'assets/images/camera.jpg'),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "invoices",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                              ),
//                            child: Center(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
//                               Navigator.push(
//                                 context,
//                                 MaterialPageRoute(
//                                     builder: (context) => Invoices()),
//                               );
//                             },),),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

if you really want the `Elevated Button`, then the right position to put it is under the `Container` widget as one of the children of the `Stack` widget. You can cut out the commented part and paste it under the `Container` widget inside the `Stack`.

And some widget has required properties, the `Elevated Button` has a `child:` property that is required and a `Text` widget is usually assigned to this property.

And try to understand the fundamentals first.